# Set boundaries to the world in Swift 3.0 SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make the game, but I stuck on camera movement with player. I need to set max camera and player x position, but I get infinite movement to the right or left.

I was tying to use override func didFinishUpdate()

```
override func didFinishUpdate() {
    cam.position.x = player.position.x
}
```

and here I tried to set world size

```
    worldNode = SKSpriteNode()
    worldNode?.size.width = backGroundImage.size.width
    self.addChild(worldNode!)
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func keepPlayerInBounds() {
  if player.position.x < frame.minX + player.size.width/2 {
    player.position.x = frame.minX + player.size.width/2
  }
}
```

put this in update, then add the other 3 boundaries (the above is the left boundary)

this also assumes player.anchorPoint is 0.5